# El constructor de File de Javascript no recibe los parámetros correctamente

Tags: javascript, archivo, base64, blob

He estado intentando probar diversas implementaciones para construir un fichero a partir de un base64 y básicamente siempre indican la función:

```
function base64ToFile(sB64DataURI, sFileName) {
        var bytes = sB64DataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ?
            atob(sB64DataURI.split(',')[1]) :
            window.unescape(sB64DataURI.split(',')[1]),
            mime = sB64DataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0],
            max = bytes.length,
            ia = new Uint8Array(max);

        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            ia[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return new File([ia], sFileName, {
            type: mime
        });
    }
```

Cuando observo el objeto que devuelve la función veo que no lo ha construido bien, porque el constructor tiene confundidos los argumentos y no se asignan correctamente. El resultado de la ejecución es esta:

[image: Captura de pantalla de la ejecución de la función y contenido del objeto devuelto]

Nunca he trabajado con esto, y probablemente se me esté pasando hacer algo previamente. ¿Alguien sabría que puede estar pasando? Creo que aportado toda la información, en cualquier caso, si alguien necesita más, me comenta.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano! Saludos.

P.S.: El base64 es una imagen que necesito convertirla a objeto File.

**EDIT**: Un console.log del resultado de la función es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [JS tiene su propia función](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) para devolverte el archivo en base64, ¿por qué reinventar la rueda?

Comment: Hol, perdona, quiero lo contrario. Lo tengo en Base64 y quiero tenerlo en un objeto File.

Comment: Depuración básica: haz un `console.log(VARIABLE)` después de crear o asignar cada variable, así sabrás lo que está fallando.

Comment: Hola, el resultado de la función ya lo había puesto en una captura, he subido de nuevo otra para que quede aún más claro. En esta se aprecian los campos del objeto File que no corresponden a los datos introducidos por el argumento. Las variables del argumento están indicadas como lo requiere el objeto File según la documentación, sin embargo, al implementarlo en Chrome, estos no se asignan correctamente para formar un objeto File.

Comment: Hola, @PabloCastañoSantiago. Creo que es una tontería, sólo prueba esta línea `return new File([...ia], sFileName, { type: mime })`

Comment: Hola, al final descubrí por qué era. Resulta que estoy utilizando Cordova, y uno de los plug-in estaba sobrescribiendo el objeto nativo File, por lo que el constructor no servía. He desactivado el plu-in y ya funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contesto yo mismo a mi pregunta dado que encontré el porqué.

Resulta que estoy utilizando Cordova y hay un plug-in (cordova-plugin-file) que reescribe totalmente el objeto nativo File, por lo que sustituye el código nativo por el suyo propio.

Mi decisión ha sido desactivar el plug-in para que no entre en conflicto con este.

Saludos.